# Can't open database 'Options' menu

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I am using MS Access 2013 and when I click on the File tab, then click on "Options", the Options screen does not appear.

I want to place a password on this database, but I cannot until I open the database up in exclusive mode and to do this, I need to go into the Options.

Does anyone have any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Open Microsoft Access from the start menu. Then go to file. Under file, click open. Click on Computer. Navigate to and select the database you want to open and don't do anything. There should be a small arrow beside the Open button. Click on it and select the open exclusive option.

Comment: Thanks Billy - Opening the db Exclusively seems to be essential.